# Is the scalar field $ X \mapsto \mbox{tr} \left( X A X^T B \right) $ always convex?

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, trace, scalar-fields

If the matrices $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite, is the scalar field $$ X \mapsto \mbox{tr} \left( X A X^T B \right) $$ always convex? I get an error when I put this in CVX even though I double-checked that $A$ and $B$ do not have negative eigenvalues.

---

<sub>**Related:** [Is the function $X \mapsto \mbox{trace} \left( X X^T \right)$ convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/188165)</sub>

Comment: What is $X?$ An arbitrary matrix?

Comment: Yes its an arbitrary matrix

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is $trace(Y Y^T)$ where $Y = B^{1/2} X A^{1/2}$ is a linear function of $X$, so it is indeed convex.

Comment: Indeed; and this in turn means that $\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(XAX^TB)=\|B^{1/2}XA^{1/2}\|_F^2$, which can be represented in CVX as `square_pos(norm(sqrtm(B)*X*sqrtm(A),'Fro'))`.

Answer (score 0):

If $B$ is positive semi-definite, it is equal to $CC^t,$ so your expression is equal to $\mathrm{trace}((C^t X) A (C^t X)^t).$ This is basically just the Frobenius norm of the vector $C^t X,$ which is a linear function of $X,$ and is convex (strictly if $A, B$ are positive definite, not strictly otherwise).